# PHP Selenium. Find element faster

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

At the moment, my code successfully enters the site and enters the login and password.
To check whether the login and password are correct, I use the following code.

```
time.sleep(5)
    try:
        driver.find_element(*Locators.MSG_ERROR_LOGIN)
        print('Error')
        return False
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('SUCCESS')
        return True
```

That is, after authorization, the code waits for 5 seconds and looks for an error, if there is one, it sends a False message. That is, the login and password are incorrect.

And if there is no such error, it sends a message to True. That is, the login and password are correct.

The problem is that it is critical for me that the code does not wait extra seconds.
I need the code to look for the error locator and the successful authorization window locator after authorization.
That is, if an error locator is found, it is false.
If the locator of successful authorization is found, then true.

Help me please with edit this bellow code.
It should work like this, whatever element it found, that's the response it sent(true or false)

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(Locators.MSG_ERROR_LOGIN))
print('Error')
return False
or
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(Locators.MSG_SUCCESS_LOGIN))
print('SUCCESS')
return True
```

Comment: You forgot to include the HTML you're targeting. It's very hard to write code to interact with a website if we have no idea what the site consists of!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.